# QGIS: duplicate layer entries in layer list

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I have the following issue when I connect to my Oracle db with the QGIS layer manager. The views I am using are duplicated like showed by this print screen;

[image: Duplicate entries in layer list]

I thought it was a primary key issue as I am using views without any primary keys, I tried to add one but without any success.

How can I correctly set up my Oracle db in order to avoid this issue?

I am using QGIS 3.16.9 on Windows 10 with a MSI installation.

Comment: Just to be clear: by QGIS 16.9 you actually mean QGIS 3.16.9, right ?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is 3.16.9

Comment: Thanks to QGIS dev support I managed to define a primary keys and a bug was open on gith hub. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45419. Nevertheless I still have the duplicate issue from out the browser. As it is visible on this print screen;